# How to change Scaffold color for selected select?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two screens. On the first screen, there is a drop-down list with colors and a "Next" button. The user selects a color and presses the "Next" button, then gets to another screen. And I need the color of the Scaffold on the other screen to be the color that the user chose on the next select after clicking the button.
How can this be implemented? And how can you correctly transfer colors to a select, so that you can then transfer them to another screen?
First Screen:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColorPickerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ColorPickerWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ColorPickerWidget> createState() => _ColorPickerWidgetState();
}

class _ColorPickerWidgetState extends State<ColorPickerWidget> {
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> get dropdownItems{
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> colorItems = [
      DropdownMenuItem(
        value: 'Red',
          child: Text('Red'),
      ),
      DropdownMenuItem(
        value: 'Blue',
          child: Text('Blue'),
      ),
    ];
    return colorItems;
  }

  // default value of select
  String selectedValue = "Red";

  // next step nav
  void _changeColor() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/text_value');
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Choose a color'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            DropdownButton(
            value: selectedValue,
            items: dropdownItems,
              onChanged: (String? newValue){
              setState(() {
                selectedValue = newValue!;
              });
            },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: _changeColor, child: Text('Next'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Main.dart:

```js
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      routes: {
         '/': (context) => HomeScreenWidget(),
         '/color_picker': (context) => ColorPickerWidget(),
         '/text_value': (context) => TextValueScreen(),
       },
       initialRoute: '/',
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You will have to pass the selected value to the Widget where you have defined MaterialApp and then change the Theme's primary color to user selected one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `selectedValue` to next widget. And build the next screen accordingly.

```
class ColorPickerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ColorPickerWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ColorPickerWidget> createState() => _ColorPickerWidgetState();
}

class _ColorPickerWidgetState extends State<ColorPickerWidget> {
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> get dropdownItems {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> colorItems = [
      const DropdownMenuItem(
        value: 'Red',
        child: Text('Red'),
      ),
      DropdownMenuItem(
        value: 'Blue',
        child: Text('Blue'),
      ),
    ];
    return colorItems;
  }

  // default value of select
  String selectedValue = 'Red';

  // next step nav
  _changeColor(String color) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ColorWidget(color: color),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Choose a color'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            DropdownButton(
              value: selectedValue,
              items: dropdownItems,
              onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedValue = newValue!;
                });
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => _changeColor(selectedValue),
              child: const Text('Next'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ColorWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String color;
  const ColorWidget({Key? key, required this.color}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: color == 'Red' ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your code is working) Is it possible to do this with Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/text_value')? I need exactly Replacement to use

Comment: For that you have to set up router in your app first

Comment: I added main.dart with routes. Could you suggest how to do this?

Comment: You should use `onGenerateRoute` if you want to pass data between widgets